# How to check if a specific index of an array contain a value java

Tags: java, arrays

say I had an array (Hello,1,2,HI,1,2)

How would I check if index 1 was = to 'Hello' is a very simple question, but cannot find an answer.

This is what I have tried,it is inside a for loop, my array is of type string:

```
  if(array[i] == "Hello" ){
  // do something 
  }
```

Comment: Reopened: this is not (necessarily) simply about comparing strings, but comparing an element of an array of objects to a string. (But will not lose sleep if re-closed).

Comment: @Bathsheba : the question is not precise enough to know that it is not an array of strings. Maybe it should be edited to add details about that.

Comment: They just have and it rather ruins my answer. Such is life ;-(

Answer (score 2):

```
if ("Hello".equals(array[i])){
    // do something
}
```

is, in many ways, the best way.

This will work

1. If `array[i]` is `null`.
2. If `array[i]` is a type other than a `java.lang.String`

I appreciate that you're a beginner and these *yoda expressions* are not to everyone's taste, but I couldn't resist.

(Note that a single `=` is an *assignment* rather than a test for equality, and `==` compares *references* rather than *contents* for non-primitive types in Java.)

Comment: Should specify that `i` is just the index, and in his/her case: "check if index 1 was = to 'Hello'", `i` would be just 0 or 1 depending on their understanding of index

Comment: So you re-opened this question to answer what the dupe already said?

Comment: Prior to the edit the question was notably different (and I had already answered: I, along with many folk, consider it poor form to gold hammer reopen in order to answer). It ain't now though.

Comment: It was an assignment, instead of a comparison, but OP said that he likes to compare the array item with the literal :P. Oh and yes, you answered, before reopening. That was a misunderstanding on my part. *"I, along with many folk, consider it poor form to gold hammer reopen in order to answer"* Good to hear (in case the question really is a dupe; if closing was wrong, then opening and answering would be fine imo).

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your array type. in your case it is String, so

```
if(array[i].equals("Hello") {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: This will throw an NPE if `array[i]` is `null`.

Comment: @javanoob If for example I wanted to check whether index 1 was an integer would this be possible or not, because the array is of type string

Comment: yes ; Integer.parseInt(array[i]) can parse an integer and will throw exception otherwise

Comment: @Bathsheba, yes but your answer already covers that